# Можно ли использовать Select в условии if php/sql?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Можно ли использовать select прямо в условии, а не создавать новую переменную?

Вот кусок кода:

```
for ($i=0; $i<21; $i++){ 
    $summa[$i] = 0;
 for ($j=$i; $j<121 ; $j+=20) { 
    if (('SELECT * FROM quest1 WHERE num_quest1=$j and negative = 1') is not null)
```

Выдает на это ошибку:

> "syntax error, unexpected T_STRING"

Comment: >> **if (('SELECT * FROM quest1 WHERE num_quest1=$j and negative = 1') is not null)**

Это что такое? Вы звездочки написали, чтобы выделить участок кода? И почему вы if-у передаете просто строку?

Comment: Да, но думаю звезды - лишние, уберу ка лучше. Я не хочу передавать строку, мне нужно, чтобы если данный запрос выполнится, то после if выполнялись определенные действия. А вот как сделать, чтобы запрос не строку возвращал и вообще чтобы все работало, увы, не знаю

Comment: Напиши словами, что тебе надо, а то я вообще не понял, что ты хочешь получить? И сдается мне, ты велик какой-то городишь. ))

Comment: @m_vav, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, ответ [[@shilgen](/users/12991/shilgen)](/users/12991/shilgen) неправильный, потому что вы возвращаете набор данных, которые нужно прочитать и куда-то записать, конечно, возможно все функции в ряд запихнуть и в IF, но думаю, качественнее все-таки перед IFом сделать все необходимое и потом проверять. Это и правильней и удобней, а на работу не повлияет.

Comment: Согласен, что описанное Вами более отвечает логике, просто я попробовал "использовать Select в условии if php/sql"....

Comment: @shilgen, да я понял :D

Answer (score 1):

Начну,.. думаю, что-то типа:

`if((num(sql(select....)))>0) {...`

num - функция, возвращающая количество рядов, вернет запрос.

sql - функция, которая непостредственно выполнит запрос.

Увидел ошибку: `(num_quest1=$j    and    negative = 1)` - надо в скобки брать, если сложное условие.

Сам запрос не сможет ничего вернуть.